# How to move a trained H2O BinaryModel from server to local R

Tags: r, h2o, xgboost

I trained an `xgboost` using  h2o framework in R on top of a virtual machine. I saved the model in a server's folder using the `h2o.saveModel()` function and I can correctly load it using the `h2o.loadModel()` function.

```
xgboost_model    <- h2o.xgboost(
                      x = predictors,
                      y = response,
                      training_frame = train_h2o,
                      model_id       = "xgboost_v1"
                      )
path_for_model = "/data/R/xxx/xxx/xxx/"
path_saved_model <- h2o.saveModel(xgboost_model, path = path_for_model, force = FALSE)

loaded_model     <- h2o.loadModel(path_saved_model)
```

When I download the file in the `path_for_model` directory generated by the `h2o.saveModel()` function 
 on the local hard disk I'm not able to load it on the local RStudio environment and I get the following error message

> Cannot find Builder for algo url name xgboost

:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = 
http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[1] "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find Builder for algo url 
name xgboost"                           
[2] "    hex.ModelBuilder.ensureBuilderIndex(ModelBuilder.java:141)"                                              
[3] "    hex.ModelBuilder.havePojo(ModelBuilder.java:120)"                                                        
[4] "    hex.Model.havePojo(Model.java:119)"                                                                      
[5] "    water.api.schemas3.ModelSchemaV3.fillFromImpl(ModelSchemaV3.java:73)"                                    
[6] "    water.api.schemas3.ModelSchemaV3.fillFromImpl(ModelSchemaV3.java:21)"                                    
[7] "    water.api.ModelsHandler.importModel(ModelsHandler.java:210)"                                             
[8] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                             
[9] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                             
[10] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                         
[11] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                                         
[12] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)"                                                               
[13] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:451)"                                                   
[14] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:296)"                                               
[15] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:222)"                                                  
[16] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                            
[17] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                            
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                  
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                              
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                      
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                               
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                       
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                           
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[26] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:197)"                                               
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                 
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"          
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"           
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                        
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                   
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                  
[37] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"            
[38] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                        
[39] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                         
[40] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                                                                    

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Cannot find Builder for algo url name xgboost
```

I know that there is the possibility to download the pojo and/or mojo java version of the model, but I want to get stuck to the R binary file.
I do not see any related post similar to my error anywhere.

I'm using the H2O version 3.20.0.3 with the R version 3.4.4 .

Comment: can you post what version of H2O you are using? Also can you post the generic R code format in which you saved and loaded your model?

Comment: added requested info

Comment: Thanks for adding the requested info! Is the version 3.20.0.3 the version you are running the server, locally, or both (please let me know if you have another version locally or on the server)? Can you also run `h2o.xgboost.available()` locally and see if returns TRUE or not.

Comment: In H2O-3 version 3.20.0.3 xgboost isn't supported for all platforms.  Check to make sure your laptop environment does support xgboost embedded in H2O.  Unless it's linux, it probably won't today.

Comment: Yes, finally I figured out that xgboost is not available on Windows, which is my local machine.